# Argument for Mathematically Determined Redistribution of Probability Upon Conditioning

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, density-function

The comment in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777085/under-what-set-of-conditions-is-redistribution-of-probability-mass-after-conditi) question establishes that when part of a sample space is considered to no longer be possible, how the eliminated probabilities are redistributed to the remaining sample space is uniquely mathematically determined.

Why is this the case?  Does it follow from the Kolmogorov axioms?  What is the mathematical argument that there is there no philosophical latitude available to shape the new probability distribution?

**Edit** So if we have a random variable $A$ which can take values in $\Omega = \{1,\ 2,\ 3\}$, and $B \subset \Omega$ is the event that $A \neq 3$, I'm interested in being shown why the way $\Pr(A\ |\ B)$ redistributes between $\Pr(A = 1)$ and $\Pr(A = 2)$ the probability mass that initially belonged to $B^C$ must be unique, even in the absence of a physical reason (such as with dice, where it is physically obvious that $\Pr(A = 1)$ must equal $\Pr(A = 2)$ in both $\Omega$ and $B$).

Comment: Kolmogorov indeed shown that for fixed $B\subset \Omega$ the set function $A \mapsto P_B(A):=P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ defines a new probability measure in the elementary theory. Is this what you’re asking about [in the case of some now impossible event $C$ we would here have $B=C^c=\Omega\setminus C$]?

Comment: @NapD.Lover So if we have a random variable $A$ which can take values in $\Omega = \{1,\ 2,\ 3\}$, and $B \subset \Omega$ is the event that $A \neq 3$, I'm interested in being shown why the way $\Pr(A\ |\ B)$ redistributes between $\Pr(A = 1)$ and $\Pr(A = 2)$ the probability mass which initially belonged to $B^C$ must be unique, even in the absence of a physical reason (such as with dice, where it is physically obvious that $\Pr(A = 1)$ must equal $\Pr(A = 2)$ in both $\Omega$ and $B$).

Comment: First, if $A$ is a random variable then the expression $P(A|B)$ is nonsense, since $A$ is not an *event* (things like $A=1$ or $A>2$ are events). However, you can compute, for $k=1,2,3$ the conditional probability $P(A=k | A\neq 3)$ by definition (for *events* $C$ and $D$, the conditional probability of $C$ given $D$ is defined as $P(C| D):=P(C \cap D)/P(D)$, as covered in most intro probability textbooks).

Comment: For example lets assume $A$ is equally likely to take on those $3$ values. Then $P(A\neq 3)=2/3$ and note the events $\{A=1 \} \cap \{A \neq 3\} =\{A=1\}$ thus the conditional probability becomes $P(A=1 | A\neq 3)=(1/3)/(2/3)=1/2$.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Right, so perhaps my inquiry reduces to asking to be shown why the above conditional probability formula is in fact the unique expression for conditional probabilities.  I can see why the formula is important, and holds in many cases such as imposing restrictions on the outcomes of die rolls.  However, in such cases there is some (a priori or physical) consideration imported from a discipline other than probability theory which mandates that all outcomes in the sample space be equiprobable, and that consideration is invariant under conditioning.  So for a hypothetical, fair

Comment: $3$-sided die, I have no issue with your analysis in the above comment, but if instead what it describes is three equiprobable price buckets in which a stock option might expire, or Religion A Religion B and atheism (all equiprobable), or three presidential candidates in a primary with equiprobable chances of winning, and then you eliminate the possibility of one bucket, or one religion, or one candidate, it is far less obvious to me that the initial property of equiprobability should still hold in each new, restricted sample space.

Comment: Yet the conditional probability expression implies that it does, indeed that it mathematically must, and this counterintuitive conclusion is what I'm trying to understand in terms of the Kolmogorov axioms.

Comment: The power of Kolmogorov's axiomatic theory is to put forth rules that govern operations involving probabilities, that not only match our intuitions (especially in statistical frequencies) but to abstract it away from any one interpretation. The abstract model may be empirically valid for some experiments and not others but that is where probability theory stops, and statistical theory, philosophy, physical considerations, and other outside disciplines come in.

Comment: In other words, and this will be my last comment, lest this thread becomes too long, if we assume there are three parties the next elected official could be affiliated with, that are mutually exclusive, the events represented by $D,R,I$ for democrat, republican and independent, and we assume whomever the next elected official is has equal chance of any three, then $P(D|I^c)=1/2$ once again. The model is virtually the same as the $3$-sided die above. Undoubtedly, this simple political model is probably not empirically realistic, but mathematically there is nothing wrong with it, per se.